# How String format() to format the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I plan to use the string.format() to make the output more readable.
I have 'Name' and 'BirthDate' and 'Salary' columns.

I got the widest string 'Name' (widest_name = 5) and widest  string 'BirthDate' (widest_birthDate = 16).

My date set: `data_set = [["Dan", "August 8 1954", "50k"], ["Jason", "December 26 1984", "90k"], ...]`

I want to have the string formatting (.format() method) with you widest Name and BirthDate.

Output:

```
Name      BirthDate             Salary
Dan       August 8 1954         50k
Jason     December 26 1984      90k
```

My code:

```
print("{0: <widest_name }, {1: <widest_birthDate }, 'Salary'".format("Name", "BirthDate"))

for lists in data_set :
    print(lists[0], lists[1], lists[2])
```

But I got the error: **builtins.ValueError: Invalid format specifier**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly write a variable inside `{}`.This is the correct format.

```
data_set = [["Dan", "August 8 1954", "50k"], ["Jason", "December 26 1984", "90k"]]
widest_name = 5
widest_birthDate = 16
print("{:<{width_name}} {:<{width_date}} {}".format("Name", "BirthDate","Salary",width_name=widest_name,width_date=widest_birthDate))
for lists in data_set :
    print("{:<{width_name}} {:<{width_date}} {}".format(lists[0], lists[1], lists[2],width_name=widest_name,width_date=widest_birthDate))


Name  BirthDate        Salary
Dan   August 8 1954    50k
Jason December 26 1984 90k
```

refer [this](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: Yes, my question is that I do not know how to specify the width using the variable. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use f strings in Python 3.6.

```
widest_name = 5
widest_birthdate = 16
print(f"{'Name':<{widest_name}} {'Birthdate':<{widest_birthdate}} Salary".format())
for lists in data_set:
    print(f"{lists[0]:<{widest_name}} {lists[1]:<{widest_birthdate}} {lists[2]}".format()
```

Result

```
Name  Birthdate            Salary
a     b                    c
d     e                    f
h     i                    l
```